# Rails Server on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn ruby on rails after purchasing a book called Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl

I have followed an Installation guide https://www.railstutorial.org

I think I've installed everything correctly, But I expected to find the rails installed in Bin folder. Can't seem to locate it...

I've done some noddy stuff like ....

```
irb(main) > hi  Hello World....  bla
irb(main) 3+2
=>5
```

But when I type the following I am getting all this ?

```
nick@Ubuntu:/bin$ rails server

Usage:
rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
-r, [--ruby`enter code here`=PATH]      # Path     to the Ruby binary of     your choice
# Default: /usr/bin/ruby
-m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some   application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
[--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
-B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle    install
-G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore   file
[--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control   .keep files
-O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active   Recordfiles
-S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets   files
[--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring   application preloader
-d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for   selected database (options: `enter code   here`mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsq
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks,  NickB

Comment: if `rails -v` is showing you rails version it means its already installed. Secondly the output you have showed confirms that rails is already there. This `rails server` command you can run from the directory which contains rails project. So first you need to read more chapters of your book how to create rails project then you can try this command. And we will be happy to help if you will stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to run `rails new name_of_app` then you can run rails server inside the app folder

Answer (score 1):

@Nick Barson , Your code shows that you are in `/bin` folder . 
You must make sure that you are on a existing pre created or initialized rails application directory path. 
like,

```
 $ rails new some_app
 $ cd some_app
 $ rails server
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your rails version:

```
$ rails -v
```

If no rails install yet, install the rails using this command:

```
$ gem install rails
```

You have to create at first an app, then have to run the server as like:

```
$ rails new demo
$ cd demo
$ rails server
```